# Boostrap grid implement margin right and top

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my html

```css
.div1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
}
.div2 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 100px;
}
.div3 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
}
.div4 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 100px;
}
.div5 {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container main-content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 div1">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 div2">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 div3">3</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 div4">4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 div5">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And output is

[image: output]

But my original grid system is

[image: original]

A margin in top and right.

How can I implement this on bootstrap grid system

Comment: You want to have spacing between rows and columns, right?

Comment: yes I need spacing between adjacent div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use standard Bootstrap approach and add divs inside columns:

```
<div class="container main-content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6"><div class="div1">1</div></div>
      <div class="col-md-6"><div class="div2">2</div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"><div class="div3">3</div></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><div class="div4">4</div></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><div class="div5">5</div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It will give you gutter between columns. If 30px is to much you can overwrite Bootstrap CSS.

To add margin-top simply, add it to the div1, div2 etc.

```
.div1,
.div2,
.div3,
.div4,
.div5{
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Working example: https://codepen.io/paweljanicki/pen/wzdazq

Comment: Check out my pen https://codepen.io/paweljanicki/pen/wzdazq - Bootstrap columns have padding, it creates the spacing between them. I think that there is no need to use margin-right.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to implement this for every col?

try to override the bootstrap col classes:

```
col-md-1 {margin: 2px 2px 0px 0px;}
col-md-2 {margin: 2px 2px 0px 0px;}
```

... till

```
col-md-12 {margin: 2px 2px 0px 0px;}
```

if there is no change, force it with !important.

```
col-md-6 {margin: 2px 2px 0px 0px !important;}
```

Comment: can you set a margin in firebug?

Answer (score 0):

**css:**

```
.margin-right-10px{
margin-right:10px;
}
.margin-left-10px{
margin-left:10px;
}

.margin-5px{
margin-left:5px;
margin-right:5px;
}
.margin-top{
margin-top:1px;
}
```

**js**

```
$(".col-md-6").firstChild.addClass(margin-right-10px);
$(".col-md-6").secondChild.addClass(margin-left-10px);

$(".col-md-4").firstChild.addClass(margin-right-10px margin-top);
$(".col-md-4").secondChild.addClass(margin-5px margin-top);
$(".col-md-4").lastChild.addClass(margin-left-10px margin-top);
```

You can change css as you wish.